# Data Center Automation tools and Novell Suse Linux?

Tags: automation, patch-management, novell, provisioning, sles

I'm looking for info to automate the patching/updating process for several hundred **Suse** machines.
Apart from **Zenworks** and [SMT](http://www.novell.com/linux/smt/) is there other patch management/automation tools you know with good support on Novell SLES OS?

I found several tools but mainly for Windows...
Do you have any experience with the following tools and Novell SLES servers?
- [Patchlink](http://www.lumension.com/vulnerability-management/patch-management-software.jsp?rpLangCode=1&rpMenuId=150833) from lumension
- Tivoli Provision Manager from IBM
- [Bigfix](http://www.bigfix.com/content/products)
- HP Server Automation
- [BMC Bladelogic](http://www.bmc.com/products/offering/bmc-bladelogic-operations-manager.html)
- [CA Spectrum Automation Manager](http://www.ca.com/us/server-provisioning.aspx)

The datacenter to keep updated is composed around 600 servers both real and virtual running SLES version 10 mainly (but SLES 9 also present).

I think SMT could do most part of the job but it seems to come short regarding reporting and inventory. Do you know of complementary tools for these aspects ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Quick question: What hardware? Sometimes the vendor solutions for hardware/inventory/configuration management are better than 3rd party solutions.

Comment: It's mainly HP servers...

Answer (score 2):

As you have HP server and you mention HP datacenter.

The tool who do that for HP is Server Automation, it's support Suse 9 and 10 for :

- OS provisioning
- patching
- application deployment
- audit and compliance
- inventory

It's also able to integrate with iLo to automate OS provisioning.

Comment: Do you know how does it retrieve the RPM from Novell servers ?  
I have seen in the manuals there is a tool for RHN (rhn_import) but nothing for Suse.  
So I wonder if it is a manual process to import the RPM in the SA repository...

Comment: rhn_import will ork only with red hat network.
You can build your own tool, by using one of the SA interface (python/java/cli).

Comment: importing SuSE patches *is* a manual process, though automating it is not horribly difficult

Answer (score 1):

From an official Novell perspective, the available tools are SMT (Subscription Management Tool) and ZLM (Zenworks Linux Management).

SMT is a free tool that simply accesses your entitled Suse subscriptions on Novell's servers, and lets you cache the patches and updates locally.  This lets you update a large number of servers without sending your bandwidth usage through the roof.  This is strictly a pull arrangement, though.  Your systems can connect to the SMT server for their packages, but this is not a system for automatically distributing the packages.

ZLM is a web-based tool for administering your Suse (and Red Hat) systems in your datacenter.  It is licensed on a per physical machine basis.  It enables you to push packages to the systems using policies and schedules (as well as manually).

Beyond those official Novell tools, it starts to get a little bit murky.  You can cobble something together with various open-source tools, such as Puppet.